# Problems with openssl_decrypt

Tags: php, encryption

So I'm trying to create an encryption app and I'm running into one fundamental problem. They are filtered/sanitized with these functions:

`strip_tags()` and `addslashes()`

It is then encrypted with AES-256-CBC using OpenSSL. So this:

```
My encrypted shopping list:

- Milk
- Eggs
- Beans

Don't forget the receipt.
```

Works fine, though it escapes the single quotes obviously. So I get `Don\'t` which isn't wanted as it will ruin the user experience. Though, as soon as I take away the `addslashes()`, the `openssl_decrypt()` function returns false.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you are just going to encrypt the data, why do you need to use `strip_tags` and `addslashes`.  You can just store/encrypt the data as-is.  You should only need to sanitize it when displaying it.

Comment: Are you having trouble *encrypting* or *decrypting*?

Comment: @RocketHazmat decrypting. This problem only occurs when I'm storing non-sanitized encrypted data...

Comment: That makes no sense.  How are you storing/retrieving the encrypted data?

Comment: @RocketHazmat I know right. I am storing the encrypted string in a database alongside the IV. This is then fetched on request (with MySQLi) and then the data is decrypted as such. It's strange how all times it will work except with the exception of a few times where it will not work at all. It's confusing me so much...

Comment: Are you doing anything to the string after encrypting it?  Or just storing it?

Comment: @RocketHazmat so I just ran a few tests so I successfully stored and retrieved my string, it seems to be things like several line breaks is causing it to break, I think that could be the culprit. Though, I am literally just encrypt->store string and IV and then retrieve->decrypt

Comment: @RocketHazmat Okay, so it seems as though if I send over something like just the word test on a new line hundreds of times, it will break it. Is there a reason why this may be?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that the encrypted data and/or IV is being modified.  Either by your DB, code, or something else.  Encryption/decryption shouldn't care about the *contents* of the data.

Comment: @RocketHazmat I just wanna clarify, there's no byte limit to an encrypted string right?

Comment: Shouldn't be.  Encryption algorithms may pad your data to a certain size, but it shouldn't matter.

Comment: @RocketHazmat well I tried with just the word "test" on a new line over and over again. This broke it. Do you know how I would prevent this from breaking it in a production envrionment?

Comment: Can you show the code that you are using to encrypt/decrypt?  I did a test and it works fine: https://3v4l.org/bKCNf

Comment: Are you using the `OPENSSL_RAW_DATA` option?

Comment: @RocketHazmat nope. Though, I've found the problem and need help remedying it. So the string that was generated from the encryption was like 4 times as long as the string that was actually stored in the DB. I have that column set to a LONGTEXT, though only short strings are working properly. How does one resolve this?

Comment: You could use `OPENSSL_RAW_DATA` to make `openssl_encrypt` give you binary data.  Then you could try storing that in a `BLOB` field in the db.

Comment: @RocketHazmat well as far as I'm aware, all I need to do is find out why only part of my encrypted string is being stored in my DB. So how would we go around tackling this?

Comment: @RocketHazmat I used your method and so far all the encrypted string is in. `$encryptedString = openssl_encrypt($content, 'AES-256-CBC', $key, $options = OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv = $this->genInitVector());` is my encryption line. Do I need to use `OPENSSL_RAW_DATA` in the decryption string?

Comment: I would assume you'd need to pass `OPENSSL_RAW_DATA` when calling `openssl_decrypt`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat woops, it seems to be just any string over a certain length that is breaking it now? :/

Comment: @RocketHazmat it generally seems as though strings like "some text" and similar are fine, but anything longer/more complex will run into the issue.

Comment: Sounds like your database field isn't large enough to hold the data.  That's why I suggested `BLOB`.  Is it still not working with that?  You can also try `LONGBLOB` (or `MEDIUMBLOB`).

Comment: @RocketHazmat tried both of those, nothing seems to be working.....

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, my recommendation is simple: Don't escape/sanitize input. This is precisely why magic quotes is disabled in newer versions of PHP.

In 99.99% of situations, [if you need to prevent SQL injection, use prepared statements](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/preventing-sql-injection-in-php-applications-easy-and-definitive-guide).

> Though, as soon as I take away the addslashes(), the openssl_decrypt() function returns false.

This sounds odd. Can you post a snippet with a fake key on 3v4l.org and share the link here?